# Where else are teachers not paid for prep time?

Tags: teaching, salary

Last spring I did some teaching at a university. It was my first time. It was a temporary position. I was there 1 semester only. I was paid by the hour.

A couple of things caught my eye about the arrangement:

1. They only paid for the time I spent teaching in *a scheduled group setting*.
2. They did not pay for *prep time*.

By prep time, I mean the time I spent getting ready for a particular class. I saw this term being used elsewhere on SE Academia, not sure how common it is...

In what countries / universities / contexts is it common to not pay teachers for the time they spend preparing a lecture?

FWIW I was teaching an undergraduate media studies course at a private *creative industries*-type university in South America.

Comment: Were you actually paid as an hourly employee, or do you mean you were paid per course hour (aka credit) taught?

Comment: Was it a stated hourly rate and your pay check only included the taught hours? Most adjunct positions in the US pay by the class/credit and therefore everyone gets paid the same regardless of how long it takes to prep.

Comment: @BryanKrause If I'm understanding you correctly, I'd say I was paid as an _hourly employee_. Thanks!

Comment: @StrongBad There was an hourly rate, and the paycheck only reflected the taught hours. Thanks!

Comment: If your university started "paying" for prep time, you would find out that the hourly wage would go down proportionately and that your pay at the end would be identical.

Answer (score 2):

It is quite common in the UK for hourly payed lecturers to bill University for contact teaching hours only. The rate is usually significantly higher than the hour worth of a full-time lecturer, to account for (unbilled) preparation time.

Comment: This describes so-called "contractual academic staff" in Australia. The higher rate incorporates preparation time, but also includes compensation for such things as superannuation and other benefits that they wouldn't receive.

Answer (score 1):

My experience is in the US, and here I think paying by the hour is very rare other than in a consulting situation where it is expected that the person already has the needed expertise and needs no prep time.

Here, one is paid by the course and in a situation like yours the pay would be (likely) very low, but not by the hour, specifically.

Since this is a private institution, it may be that they thought of it as more of a consultancy than a lectureship.